# How to delete all the keys in a dictionary maintaining the values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, key, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary but I want to get only the values, not the keys.
How can I do it?

```
`{0: 'despacio',
 1: 'mios',
 2: 'ir',
 3: 'poca',
 4: '_',
 5: 'consigue',
 6: 'eres'}

Desired output:

{'despacio',
 'mios',
 'ir',
 'poca',
 '_',
 'consigue',
 'eres'}`
```

Comment: `values = list(dictt.values())`

Comment: If you want a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) as shown in your output: `set(dic.values())`